# Is there a way to validate the content of a tfvars file without doing terraform plan?

Tags: terraform

Is there a way to validate the content of a `.tfvars` file (i.e. suitable for passing to `terraform plan -var-file foo.tfvars`) without running `terraform plan`?

Ideally validating the variable names, but even just the basic syntax would be good.

The reason for wanting to do this is we have some files that are only used in certain environments, and recently a change was committed that was syntactically incorrect - but it only got caught when attempting to deploy to that environment. I'd like to be able to detect in the pipeline that the file is invalid before running the `terraform plan` step.

For the `.tf` files themselves we can use `terraform validate`, but that won't look at variable files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution, which I don't love but seems to work, is to use `terraform console`. This requires you to have all of your variable definitions in a `variables.tf` file, and the rest of your terraform in other files.

```
mkdir temp
cp variables.tf file_to_test.tfvars temp/
cd temp/
echo '"valid"' | terraform console -var-file file_to_test.tfvars
```

`terraform console` will exit with state 0 if the file format is valid, and 1 otherwise.

You can also use this trick to extract the value of a variable:

```
echo 'var.variable_i_want_to_query' | terraform console -var-file file_to_test.tfvars
```

Although unfortunately there's no way to force this value to e.g. JSON

Comment: This is a pretty good trick... What does the echo '"valid"' bit mean in your first example?

Comment: You need to pass in something it could evaluate - it could be a number, a string, or the name of a variable. I choose the string valid so that gets echoed back

Comment: Works like a charm for me. I've had no trouble just keeping the other files in the same directory either. This should be the accepted answer, if you'd ask me 